# Need help traversing elements with jQuery in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

[image: what my page looks like]

[image]

So the first image is what my page looks like.  I am trying to grab the ID of the table at the top (the table that has the class trackingHistory and ID of ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_myRpt_ctl00_0_gdvTH_0) whenever the highlighted button is clicked.

Right now I can click the button and fire my Javascript method 'ToggleHistory()' and use jQuery to get the ID of my button.  (.attr('id'))

but that's about as far as i can get.  I have tried messing around with the closest() and prev() methods from jQuery but haven't had any luck.  any help would be appreciated.

javascript method

```
function ToggleHistory(button)
{
    console.log(button);
    var x = $(button).prev();
    var y = $(button).closest('table').find('.trackingHistory');
    //var z = $(button).closest('.trackingHistory');

    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log($(y).attr('id'));
    //console.log(z);
}
```

i dont want to have to hard code the id because there will be a dynamic amount of these tables and buttons.

Comment: Ah i didn't think of that.  let me see what I can do really quick.  screenshots were just easier for me.

Comment: Try with : `$(this).prev().find('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_myRpt_ctl00_0_gdvTH_0');`

Comment: @itsgoingdown Might be easier to `.find('.trackingHistory')` still at the end. `id`s with Web Forms are generated by the application and aren't necessarily consistent.

Comment: Yea i was hoping to not have to hard code the id

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yes you're right, should look for `.trackingHistory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<button>` and the `<table>` don't have a direct relationship, but do have the `<div>` in common.

```
<div>
  <table class="toggleHistory"></table>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="ToggleHistory(this)">click here to hide</button>
```

The `<button>` and `<div>` are immediate siblings, which you can traverse between with [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and back with [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$(button).prev()...
```

Then, the `<div>` and `<table>` are [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and child ([`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)):

```
$(button).prev().children('.trackingHistory');
```

---

```
function ToggleHistory(button)
{
    console.log(button);

    var $historyTable = $(button).prev().children('.trackingHistory');

    console.log($historyTable.attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that did it! you rock.  thanks for the clear explanation as well.